# How to compare username of current user with a specific parameter?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I need to find the username of a user and if that is same as a specific one, I will show some extra information to that user.

Using the following code I can retrieve user name of the current user but not sure how to compare it with the specific one which is ${username}.

```
 <sec:authentication property="name"/>

 <c:if test=" ? == ${username}">
   Hellow
 </c>
```

Comment: "With specific parameter" can you be more specific ? You mean like `?` in SQL. You need paramater in some variable scope.

Comment: I have provided an example >> ${username}

Comment: I was asking about "?". Anyways, As you found an answer. So, It doesn't matter now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare some varible and assign to it `principal` object:

```
<sec:authentication var="principal" property="principal" />
```

and then get username using following EL expression:

```
${principal.username}
```

So you can do something like

```
<c:if test="${principal.username == username}">
   Hellow
</c>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
<g:set var="user" value="${sec.username()}" />
<g:if test="${user == username}" >
    heelloo
</g:if>
```

Comment: hence comparing the currently logged in user , maybe thats not what you were after?